# Clear search on input by click

Tags: jquery, search, input, reset

I have a small script, that shows images by their "alt" tags using a search field.

Now I try to clear the search (not only empty the input field) by clicking a button.

But I only can fully reset by press "delete" on my keyboard, when inside the field. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
  if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
    $(".image").hide();
    var mySelector = $(this).val();
    var myImgs = $("[alt*='" + mySelector + "' i]");
    myImgs.show();
  } else {
    $(".image").show();
  }
});
```

Comment: Where is the button click code? That's the part relevant to the problem.

Comment: $(".button").click(function() {
     $('#search').val("");
   });

Comment: So then all you need to do is display all images again, `$('.image').show()`...

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not that easy. I have to explain it a little further. On the webpage there is a function, where the user can search for brands in two ways: By categroy (dropdown with filter script) and by using a search field. Here are the full scripts:

```
    //Brands Filter 
    var $btns = $('.btn-brand').click(function () {
  if (this.id == 'all') {
    $('.brand').removeClass('brand-off');
  } else {
    var $el = $('.' + this.id).removeClass('brand-off');
    $('.brand').not($el).addClass('brand-off');
  }

  $btns.removeClass('btn-brand-active');
  $(this).addClass('btn-brand-active');

});


//Free Search
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
  if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
    // hide everything,
    $(".brand").hide();
    // get the text in the input
    var mySelector = $(this).val();
    // show any alt that contains the input
    var myImgs = $("[alt*='"+mySelector+"' i]");
    myImgs.show();
  } else {
    $(".brand").show();
  }
  });
```

So if I use the search field and after that the dropdown I don't get all results, until I clear the search field manually by clicking the "delete" button when in it.